# NSMutableArray index deleting

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I'm making my slot machine app using `iCarousel`, my `iCarousel` contains images from `NSDocumentDirectory` this images was from my `ImagePicker`. So here's how my app works, when the user press a button the `iCarousel` spins.
When it stops, display the item for 3 seconds, then deletes it.

My problem is when I go to another View, the deleted index/item is there again. How to maintain my array even I go to different views. That the deleted index/item will not be shown, only until the app was restarted, like saving an array. Thanks for the help.

// my array

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.images = [NSMutableArray new];  
    for(int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) 
    { 
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

        NSString *savedImagePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"images%d.png", i]]; 
            if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:savedImagePath]){ 
                [images addObject:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:savedImagePath]]; 
            } 
    } 
}



- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {    
    spinButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [spinButton addTarget:self action:@selector(spin) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:spinButton];
}
- (void) carouselDidEndScrollingAnimation:(iCarousel *)carousel{
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.56 //this arranges the duration of the scroll
                                     target:self
                                   selector:@selector(deleteItem)
                                   userInfo:nil
                                    repeats:NO];   
}
```

// spin and delete method

```
- (void)spin {
        [carousel scrollByNumberOfItems:-35 duration:10.7550f];
}

-(void) deleteItem {
    //Removes the object chosen 
        NSInteger index = carousel.currentItemIndex;
        [carousel removeItemAtIndex:index animated:YES];
        [images removeObjectAtIndex:index];
}
```

What I need is, when the index/item is deleted, it will not be shown temporarily even if I go to other views. The views will only be restarted after app is closed and open again

Comment: where you are creating this array i.e. in which method and when you are deleting elements from the array?

Comment: If you are not creating the view every time, u need to reproduce the array in viewWillAppear. Else you can use only one array for both the views and that array can be defined in app delegate. More Simpler way :)

Comment: @DimplePanchal tried the viewWillAppear, but doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is your are creating the images `NSMutableArray` every time you enter the view.

As @Saleh said you should place the array outside your view controller. To do it in the `appDelegate`, like he was suggesting, do the following:

In **AppDelegate.h** declare:

```
@property( strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *images;
```

In **AppDelegate.m**:

```
@synthesize images;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Read the images after the existing code ....

    self.images = [NSMutableArray array];
    for(int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) 
    { 
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

        NSString *savedImagePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"images%d.png", i]]; 
        if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:savedImagePath]){ 
            [images addObject:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:savedImagePath]]; 
        } 
    }     

    return YES;
}
```

Then in your **ViewController.m**:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
```

and change your `viewDidLoad` method:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.images = ((AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]).images;
}
```

This should work.

Comment: What I need is, when the index/item is deleted, it will not be shown temporarily even if I go to other views. The views will only be restarted after app is closed and open again.

Comment: Yes I know, and this is what you can achieve with this answer. Have you tried it?

Comment: Can you tell me what is the exact problem after trying it, please?

Comment: There is no problem in your code, but when I go to another view controller, the image/index that was deleted is still there AGAIN,

Comment: That could only be if: 1. You are no deleting the image properly (is `deleteItem` getting called?) 2. You are still reading the images in the `viewDidLoad` method instead of what I suggested 3. The `viewController` never gets deallocated and what you are seeing is the image in the control (UIImageView or whatever) that you are using to show it (is `viewDidLoad` called when you go back to your view?)

Comment: deleteItem is being called, I have put it in the viewDidLoad like what you suggested, I'm using ARC in storyboard,

Comment: I am sorry, I can't help you any further with this information. You should realize that it is impossible with my solution, to have the deleted images in the array as you are not accessing `NSFileManager` in your view. Good luck!

Comment: Hi how ro reload this in a viewcontroller

Answer (score 0):

Use one instance of the array, you are initializing it only once. Put the array in appDelegate which will make it singelton for the whole app.

Comment: could you give me some snippet?

Comment: Just add the array in appDelegate. Make it a property, initial/memory allocation in applicationDidFinishLaunching and use it in your views by accessing it through the property.

Comment: added it in applicationDidFinishLaunching, make it a property, but when i use it in my CarouselView., nothing appears.

Comment: did you initialize it? and checked that it has your required data?